# Generate key and CSR in IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, certificate-signing-request, ibm-certificate-manager, key-protect

For a custom application on IBM Cloud, I need to be able to generate private key and CSR in IBM Cloud. Is there a service in IBM Cloud which would allow me to generate a private key & CSR in service itself? I checked the certificate manager & key protect service but none of them provide such capability. I wouldn't want someone to manually generate the private key on his/her machine or an on-premise server and upload it to the cloud. Is there any way in IBM Cloud to accomplish this? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can order SSL certificates in IBM Cloud. See the [SSL Certificate service which is part of the infrastructure offerings](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/ssl-certificates/index.html#getting-started-with-ssl-certificates).

Working with Let's Encrypt it is also pretty simple to obtain and deploy certificates. Here is information on [wildcard certificates with Kubernetes / container apps](https://blog.4loeser.net/2018/07/secure-apps-on-ibm-cloud-kubernetes.html), [wildcard certificates with Cloud Foundry apps](https://blog.4loeser.net/2018/07/bringing-lets-encrypt-ibm-cloud.html), and how to [generate and deploy a certificate for just a single app using a wrapper](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/08/securing-custom-domains-lets-encrypt/).